# How can I convert a ttf font to svg font, which works with batik rasterizer (svg->pdf)?

Tags: svg, fonts, batik

I'm converted a ttf font with [batik ttf2svg](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/tools/font-converter.html) into a svg font. The svg font is then used in a svg, which I want to convert into a pdf. This is done with [batik rasterizer](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/tools/rasterizer.html).

As it was a bit tricky to get it working I share my solution here.

Answer (score 0):

batik [ttf2svg](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/tools/font-converter.html) was the only converter that I got to work at the end. Other tools did not work - at least in combination with batik rasterizer.

I used following command to convert the font:

`java -jar /path/to/batik/batik-1.8/batik-ttf2svg-1.8.jar diehl_deco.ttf -o diehl_deco.svg -id DiehlDeco -l 32 -h 20000`

The option `-l 32` is essential - at least for the font Diehl Deco - as the first 32 unicode characters are not compatible with batik rasterizer. If your font does not render at all a single character in the svg font can be the problem.
`-h` is just a big value to get all following characters, maybe you could even skip that one.